# Android Studio SDK not installed

Tags: android, sdk

I was trying to download Android Studio on windows 64-bit. The installation process was going smoothly but an error occurred during the process that said "The following SDK components were not installed: Android Emulator, Android SDK Platform-tools and Sources for Android 29"

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Top menu -> Tools -> SDK Manager:

1. Tab `SDK Platform` -> select needed Android (you may need Android 9)
2. Tab `SDK Tools` -> Android Emulator, Android SDK Platform-tools, Android SDK tools